# UIKeyboard without number

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uikeyboard

I need a UIKeyboard that display the default UIKeyboardType without the number 0-9. I only need to hide those buttons.

Is there a way to access the the different button of the keyboard so i could set then hidden?
If no, can i detect when the ".?123" button is pressed AND add a subview to cover the first row?
Or any pointer to a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no public API for disabling access to the number and punctuation keys.  You could dig through the keyboard's view hierarchy to try to hide the number toggle key, but that is likely to break in the future (the keyboard view hierarchy has changed in the past).

It would be much simpler to just filter out the characters you don't like in your text control's delegate.  For example, let's say you only want to allow the user to type in letters.  If you have a `UITextField`, set its delegate to your view controller and implement this method in your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSRange all = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
    if (all.length == 0) {
        // deletion
        return YES;
    }

    NSRange letters = [string rangeOfCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
    return NSEqualRanges(all, letters);
}
```

If you have a `UITextView`, the method is called `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I've come up with this :
`NSRange letters = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURTUVWXYZ., :;()-/+$&@?!"]];`

The only problem is that the backspace is ignored.

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow deletion.  Your character set will not make users of other languages happy.  I hope that's ok with you.

Comment: Came up with a convenient solution thank to you : 
`if (all.length == 0) {
        // deletion
        return YES;
    }
NSMutableCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]; 
    [charset addCharactersInString:@".,:;()-/+$&@?! "];
    NSRange letters = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charset];
    return NSEqualRanges(all, letters);`